# How do I stop this from disappearing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to do a pygame code here, but it isn't working how I want to, I want to fix this circle on the screen, can you guys help me please?

```
while True:
    clock.tick(60)

    window.blit(bg, (0,0))

    # circulo #

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_q:
                clock.tick(1)
                pg.draw.circle(window, (5,5,5), [120, 120], 60, 1)
                continue
```

Comment: Could you put the output/image here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're (probably) clearing the screen every frame with the `window.blit(bg, (0,0))`.

Then if the user presses <kbd>q</kbd>, for that frame only, a circle is drawn.  After a few more *milliseconds* (maybe less than 1), the background is re-drawn.  So depending on your system, the human may *never* notice the circle being drawn.

One way to fix this, is to just set a boolean "flag" so the circle is re-painted until the flag changes back again.

```
draw_circle = False   # Should the circle be drawn?

while True:
    clock.tick(60)

    # re-draw the scene
    window.blit(bg, (0,0))

    # circulo #
    if draw_circle:
        pg.draw.circle(window, (5,5,5), [120, 120], 60, 1)

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_q:
                draw_circle = not draw_circle  # toggle circle on/off
```